# JS slider/carousel - staggered and jerky transition between background images when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the website: http://54.169.61.153/coffeehouse/merchandise/mobile-apps/starbucks-mobile-applications-2

[image: the section with slider]

The image above is the section of my jerky slider. Scrolling is smooth but the animation to switch between each carousel item when I click on the icon is not smooth. The actions feel quite staggered and jerky - I'm not sure where I went wrong - would this be my css/js. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem must be related to fade in and out of background images. You should skip the slides between the starting and target slides when one of the buttons is clicked! Also note that SO is not a debugging service!

Comment: @Vohuman I'm not taking it as a debugging service, I'm still learning. I wouldn't be here if I could figure out how to do this